# Pure functions and Java

Tags: java, lambda, functional-programming

I have several doubts about Java and pure functions. As far as I know, a pure function is a function for which these two statements hold:

1. No side-effects.
2. Same results given the same input.

According to that (and as an example), this function would be pure:

```
int sum(int a, int b) { return a + b; }
```

However, **would this function be considered pure?**

```
int sum(Person a, Person b) { return a.getAge() + b.getAge(); }
```

My guess is no, because the result is different depending on the Person objects that you pass as parameters to the function.

Taking into account that objects in Java (and OO languages in general) have hidden information, **could any function that involves objects as parameters be considered pure?**

Another question, **can a language/program be considered pure if any of its functions is not pure?**

Taking into consideration all this, **could a Java program (fairly complex) be composed only of pure functions (be pure, so to say) or is it just something impossible?**

Another question, as far as the compiler is concerned, a lambda expression can only use final (or effectively final) variables:

```
// Correct
int f = 0;
IntStream.of(1,2,3).map(e -> e * f).forEach(System.out::println);

// Compilation error
int g = 0;
IntStream.of(1,2,3).map(e -> e * g).forEach(System.out::println);
g = 22;
```

**How is it possible that that being the case this code compiles?**

```
// Correct
int[] f = new int[]{ 0 };
IntStream.of(1,2,3).map(e -> e * f[0]).forEach(System.out::println);
f[0] = 25;
```

Comment: [This question should answer your first question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22395311/difference-between-pure-and-impure-function)

Comment: "because the result is different depending on the Person objects that you pass as parameters to the function" - uh, so? The result of the function that took integers is different depending on the integers you pass it. Most pure functions give different outputs if you give them different inputs.

Comment: `because the result is different depending on the Person objects that you pass` - the first function results is different depending the int parameters you pass too. It's a pure function to me, it would not be pure if it modified some of the objects' internal fields

Comment: This is five questions.  You should really ask them as five separate questions.

Comment: @BackSlash unless there's a `setAge` method in `Person`.  If there were, you could pass the same two `Person` objects to `sum` and get a different result the second time.

Comment: @DavidWallace Why? Even with a `setAge` method inside the object, the function doesn't call it (so no side effects) and it relies on two defined inputs. For each pair, there is one and only one output, so the function seems pure to me.

Comment: If I'm allowed to change the age of a `Person`, then I'm changing the value that comes out when I call `sum`.

Comment: @DavidWallace That's true, but you rely on two `int` fields: for each `int` pair, you get one and only one output, making the output of the function consistent. Maybe I'm missing something, but I think this doesn't make the function impure, as you are doing a well-defined operation with a consistent output. You can change the field's value, the output will still be consistent.

Comment: @user2357112 David Wallace make the point I wanted to make (and therefore my question). Imagine a first call to the function (Person a, Person b), with ages 1 and 2. Second call to the function, same persons but their ages were modified (now 3 and 4). Would you be able to do memoization in that case? (same paremeters, different results)

Answer (score 1):

> could any function that involves objects as parameters be considered pure?

Yes, if arguments are immutable.

> My guess is no, because the result is different depending on the Person objects that you pass as parameters to the function.

That's not correct reason. But same object can have different age at different point of time.

> can a language/program be considered pure if any of its functions is not pure?

I'm not sure, but I answer as No because the meaning of `pure` is defied by that impure function.

> How is it possible that that being the case this code compiles?

Because reference is final.

Comment: `same object can have different age at different point of time.` That's true, but you rely on two `int` fields: for each `int` pair, you get one and only one output, making the output of the function consistent. Maybe I'm missing something, but I think this doesn't make the function impure.

Comment: How is immutability relevant here? Imagine an example when an immutable class `Person` implements `getAge()` as a method with side effects - say, printing the age before returning it. This would make our `sum` impure, even though `Person` is immutable. I think something stronger than immutability is required here.

Comment: @BackSlash See you 2nd point in question. Can you say that `sum` will always return same value no matter what happens to the objects after `sum` is called. If answer is No, that means function is impure.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight `This would make our sum impure, even though Person is immutable` i don't get you. That method will always function in same way whenever it is called. if it prints, it will always print same value.

Comment: @Azodious Pure functions cannot have side effects. Printing is a side effect.

Comment: @Azodious let's think about memoization for a moment. Imagine a first call to the function (Person a, Person b), with ages 1 and 2. Second call to the function, same persons but their ages were modified (now 3 and 4). Would you be able to do memoization in that case? (same paremeters, different results)

Comment: There is possibility. You can call `sum(int, int)` from `sum(Person, Person)`

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Ok. agreed. but lets not talk about adding side-effects knowingly but finding in existing logic.